# Can't find a complete list of default pages for MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've made a change to what I thought was the main default template page in a hosted version of Sharepoint 2007, but the search page hasn't picked up the change.

Can someone please either give me a list of all the default page files, or tell me how to identify them? It's really important that I add a JS script call across all pages everywhere on the site.

Thanks!

Point of clarification: for now, I'm just trying to include a jQuery reference. I really don't think I'm trying to do anything complicated or unusual - I just want this include to be be global across all pages by default. I've modified /_catalogs/masterpage/default.master with:

```
<HEAD runat="server">
    <script src="/Global%20Site%20Files/jq1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT**
I just did a search of the source code for a statically defined meta-tag and found that the default.master I altered is in fact the only file in the search results!!! This means, as far as I understand, that my jQuery include should have worked! I'm more confused than ever...

Comment: Still not clear on your question kindly elaborate what changes you want to default page and how you made those changes

Comment: @Ashutosh - added clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue is not a question of multiple page templates or master files. The search results page (which is the primary page in question) does not use the default.master file. Moreover, even as an administrator, I don't have the ability to edit the search results page.

In the end, it looks as though I was looking for what I thought was a solution, but was really just a red herring. I'm going to repost a more specific question to my problem.

Comment: You would have to add the same script to application.master page

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh I'll try looking at that. Do you have a default path for that file to help me track it down?

Answer (score 1):

Hi What i can see is the way you are refrencing is wrong you should use full Qualified URL for 
src attribute in script tag currently you are using relative path that might be a cause of error

Comment: Thanks, but the code does work on pages where it's loaded. This isn't the issue.